# IPython Notebook showing `ImportError`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and I just installed IPython 4.0.
Now, when I type `ipython notebook` in the terminal, I get the following error message:

`ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp`

I have read related questions on this site but I could not solve this situation.

Since, I have no working knowledge of IPython,so I could really use some advice to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pip install "ipython[notebook]"`
and take a look here:
http://ipython.org/install.html#i-already-have-python.
This should install all the dependencies and get you up and running.